# Can counting rows be made any faster?

Tags: mysql, count

I need to calculate the total number of rows based on a set of criteria:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE hasPhoto=1 AND userStatus='a';
```

The above query takes 0.10 sec to run on a MyISAM table with 500,000 rows despite having a composite index on columns `userStatus` and `hasPhoto`.

Is there any better way to improve counting performance short of writing the total count in a separate table?

Comment: 0.10 seconds doesnt seem that much on 500 k rows.

Comment: @Mihai, it sure does add up when the number of rows hit 5M and above. I wonder how [Stackoverflow does it in less than 0.1sec with 6.7 million rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=447965&sort=newest).

Comment: ... it's cached?

Comment: @DigitalChris, I don't believe the back pages are cached that often to the extend that they are able to match the total number of questions with the page number x the number of rows.

Comment: StackExchange.init called on every page pulls the sidebar content via js. The entire page doesn't have to be cached monolithically; cached elements can be assembled.

Comment: @DigitalChris, actually when JS is turned off, it is equally fast.

Comment: Cached elements can be assembled server side and do not necessarily depend on the client to assemble them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are going to get anything better than the composite index. However, the key distribution for the composite index could hamper query performance depending on the (hasPhoto,userStatus) combination you choose. Here is how:

Run this Query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) rowCount,hasPhoto,userStatus FROM Users GROUP BY hasPhoto,userStatus;
```

This will show you how sparse and how dense each composite index combination is.

Sparse combinations (low rowCount) should use an index scan.

Dense combinations (high rowCount) should use a full table if the Query Optimizer believes it must read too much of the composite index.

You can try this out by running

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE hasPhoto=1 AND userStatus='a';
```

This will reveal whether the EXPLAIN plan favors an index scan (Extra column `Using where; Using index`), or a full index (or table) scan (select_type of ALL or SIMPLE).

Comment: I got a very high row count (95% of total rows). And from the explain select statement, MySQL still chooses to use the composite index. If I `IGNORE INDEX`, then the counting takes 8 times longer (0.8sec).

Comment: Looks like you can't do any better than the composite index for the count performance.

Answer (score 0):

The only improvement i could see is in careful selection of your composite index.

Putting the column that will generate more false results as first index should improve performance slightly.

Using a favorable sort order should also have an effect - for example if you used (hasPhoto=1) significantly more often than (hasPhoto=0) you should use a DESC index for that column.

Comment: The column order should not matter if the whole index is being utilized. MySQL has yet to implement DESC index.

Comment: Your answer that column order doesn't matter surprised me a bit, so I looked further. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537128/is-there-an-optimal-method-for-ordering-a-mysql-composite-index suggests otherwise.